# AngularJS ForEach push new item into object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a JavaScript object which has a list of retailers

```
var listRetailers = [
{"url":"http://www.fake1.com", "img":"images/1logo.jpg"},
 {"url":"http://www.fake2.com", "img":"images/2logo.gif"},
 {"url":"http://www.fake3.com", "img":"images/3logo.gif"},
 ]
```

I would like to PUSH a new key:value into each item:

```
object.push("storeNumber": "1");
```

So the updated JavaScript object will be

```
var listRetailers = [
{"url":"http://www.fake1.com", "img":"images/1logo.jpg", "storeNumber":"1"},
 {"url":"http://www.fake2.com", "img":"images/2logo.gif", "storeNumber":"1"},
 {"url":"http://www.fake3.com", "img":"images/3logo.gif", "storeNumber":"1"},
 ]
```

Within my angular controller I have

```
$scope.retailers = listRetailers ;

angular.forEach($scope.retailers, function(obj){
          obj.push("storeNumber": "1");
        });
```

The error states:  Object # has no method 'push'

What am I missing here?

Comment: Which part of this do you think involves JSON?

Comment: @meagar The updating of json object.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**That's because `obj` refers to your retailer object and is not an array**. [If you want to add properties to it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects), you can just define them using either the bracket `[]` notation, or by using the dot `.` notation.

```
angular.forEach($scope.retailers, function(obj){

   //Using bracket notation
   obj["storeNumber"] = 1;

   //Using dot notation
   obj.storeNumber = 1;

});
```

Comment: Is there any reason to choose one over the other, except for personal preference?

Comment: @MatthewT.Baker - Absolutely. Most of the time you should be using dot notation for clairty, but the bracket notation allows you to do things that simply aren't possible using dot notation.

For instance you could use a computed property name `obj["base" + num]`, or you might want an identifier that has characters that would otherwise not be valid syntax using dot notation.

`obj["I have spaces"]`